# Pandas Multiple headers DataFrame Stack TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue when I try to stack a DataFrame with 2 headers. Here is my df :

```
import pandas as pd

multicol = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Car', 'Megane'), ('Car', 5008)])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 4]], index=['Diesel', 'Escence'], columns=multicol)
```

When I try to stack this df I have the following error :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I think this error is due to my second header with contains both a string and an int. The problem is that my actual df comes from an Excel file.

How can I convert my second header strings ?

Comment: it's when you do df.stack() you get the error? I'm asking because it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right. If you change all types to be `str`, it works fine:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(str(c), str(v)) for c, v in df.columns.values])
>>> df.stack()

                Car
Diesel  5008    2
        Megane  1
Escence 5008    4
        Megane  2
```

Here the tuples are accessed using `df.columns.values`, then made into string tuples using list comprehension, and finally set back using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html).